# xampp installation.while installation of xampp/apache.I am having an error showing the following lines

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

while installation of xampp/apache.I am having an error showing the following lines.

```
5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Found Path: "c:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k 
runservice
5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k 
runservice
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
    5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
    5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
    5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Found Path: "c:\apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
    5:24:47 PM  [Apache]    Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k
```

From what i can see, the problem is you installed XAMPP in the wrong path, so i suggest you uninstall xampp and re-install it again making sure it's **PATH** is installed like this -->

```
    "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
```

The XAMPP folder must be in your **C-drive** or **Local disk**, that is where  Program files and Program files(x86) are.

Hopefully that helps.